# qpsolvers error: "SolverNotFound: solver 'cvxopt' is not in the list ['ecos', 'osqp', 'quadprog', 'scs'] of available solvers"

Tags: python, quadratic-programming, cvxopt

I am trying to use qpsolvers library to solve a quadratic program using the 'cvxopt' solver, but I keep getting the following error:

`SolverNotFound: solver 'cvxopt' is not in the list ['ecos', 'osqp', 'quadprog', 'scs'] of available solvers`

I am using conda environment with python version 3.10.8 and I installed the qpsolvers using pip:

`pip install qpsolvers`

I tried this on both windows and macos and I am getting the same error on both even after fresh install.

[looking into the qpsolvers/solvers/ directory does show cvxopt is indeed installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQZFp.png)

but running the following command:
`print(qpsolvers.available_solvers)`

returns: `['ecos', 'osqp', 'quadprog', 'scs']` don't know why its not detecting cvxopt

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing the library but no use. I have no idea what I am doing wrong, any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this page: https://github.com/qpsolvers/qpsolvers/issues/222 might be useful.

So, try installing it this way: `pip install "qpsolvers[cvxopt]"`

I hope, this is helpful !